# Как добавить динамическое добавление данных с консоли.

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

т.е. чтобы можно было изменить уже имеющиеся данные в классах или добавить новые

```
  #include <iostream>
 #include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

class Product { //БАЗОВЫЙ КЛАСС (В) "ПРОДУКТ"
public: 
    Product(float wight) {
    //  cout << "Конструктор класса Product" << endl;
        this->weight = wight;
    }
    virtual ~Product() {
        //cout << "Деструктор класса Product" << endl;
    }
    virtual void print() {
        cout << "Вес продукта - " << weight << " кг" << endl;
    }
protected:
    float weight;
};

class Vegetable : virtual public Product { //ПРОИЗВОДНЫЙ КЛАСС (Р1) "ОВОЩ"
public:
    Vegetable(char *name, float wight, char *group) : Product(wight) {
        cout << "Конструктор класса Vegetable" << endl;
        this->name = name;
        this->group = group;
    }
    ~Vegetable() {
        //cout << "Деструктор класса Vegetable" << endl;
    }
    void print() {
        cout << "Название овоща - " << name << ", группа - " << group << endl;
    }
protected:
    char *name;
    char *group;
};

class Cucumber : virtual public Vegetable {  //ПРОИЗВОДНЫЙ КЛАСС (Р11) "ОГУРЕЦ"
public:
    Cucumber(char *name, float wight, char *group, char *sort) : Vegetable(name, wight, group), Product(wight) {
        cout << "Конструктор класса Cucumber" << endl;
        this->sort = sort;
    }
    ~Cucumber() {
        //cout << "Деструктор класса Cucumber" << endl;
    }
    void print() {
        cout << "Сорт огурца - " << sort << endl;
    }
protected:
    char *sort;
};

class Fruit : virtual public Product {  //ПРОИЗВОДНЫЙ КЛАСС (Р2) "ФРУКТ"
public:
    Fruit(char *name, float wight, char *type) : Product(wight) {
        cout << "Конструктор класса Fruit" << endl;
        this->name = name;
        this->type = type;
    }
    ~Fruit() {
        //cout << "Деструктор класса Fruit" << endl;
    }
    void print() {
        cout << "Название фрукта - " << name << ", тип - " << type << endl;
    }
protected:
    char *name;
    char *type;
};

class Apple : virtual public Fruit {  //ПРОИЗВОДНЫЙ КЛАСС (Р21) "ЯБЛОКО"
public:
    Apple(char *name, float wight, char *type, char *color) : Fruit(name, wight, type), Product(wight) {
        //cout << "Конструктор класса Apple" << endl;
        this->color = color;
    }
    ~Apple() {
        //cout << "Деструктор класса Apple" << endl;
    }
    void print() {
        cout << "Цвет яблока - " << color << endl;
    }
protected:
    char *color;
};

class CaloricValue : public Cucumber, public Apple { //ПРОИЗВОДНЫЙ КЛАСС (Р3) "КАЛЛОРИЙНОСТЬ ПРОДУКТА"
public:
    CaloricValue(float wightProduct, char *nameProduct1, char *groupVegetable, char *sortCucumber,
        char *nameProduct2, char *typeFruit, char *colorApple) : 
        Cucumber(nameProduct1, wightProduct, groupVegetable, sortCucumber), 
        Vegetable(nameProduct1, wightProduct, groupVegetable),
        Apple(nameProduct1, wightProduct, typeFruit, colorApple),
        Fruit(nameProduct2, wightProduct, typeFruit), Product(wightProduct) {
        //cout << "Конструктор класса CaloricValue" << endl;
        this->wight = wightProduct;
    }

    ~CaloricValue() {
        //cout << "Деструктор класса CaloricValue" << endl;
    }
    void print() {
        cout << "Каллорийность огурца - " << wight*14 << " Ккал" << endl;
        cout << "Каллорийность яблока - " << wight*47 << " Ккал" << endl;
    }
private:
    float wight;
};



int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    cout << "------Продукт №1------" << endl;
    Cucumber *cucumber = new Cucumber("Огурец", 0.15, "Тыквенные", "Корнишон");
    cucumber->Product::print();
    cucumber->Vegetable::print();
    cucumber->print();
    delete cucumber;

    cout << "------Продукт №2------" << endl;
    Apple *apple = new Apple("Яблоко", 0.3, "Розоцветные", "Белый налив");
    apple->Product::print();
    apple->Fruit::print();
    apple->print();
    delete apple;

    cout << "------Каллорийность продуктов------" << endl;
    CaloricValue *caloricValue = new CaloricValue(0.15, "Огурец", "Тыквенные", "Корнишон", "Яблоко", "Розоцветные", "Белый налив");
    caloricValue->Product::print();
    caloricValue->print();
    delete caloricValue;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Переформулируйте вопрос. Абсолютно не понятно, что вы хотите услышать. Данные с консоли в C++ можно получить через стандартный ввод `std::cin`.

Comment: Для динамического добавления используйте `new.`. Хотя `new` и присутствует - что вы хотите сказать словом динамическое - не понятно. Возможно вам нужен список `List` (динамический массив)

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, попробуйте организовать меню с функциями : 1 - добавление в список (можно использовать для удобства, контейнеры STL, такие как std::vector или std::list)). 2 - изменение данных, при этом измененные данные определяются по вводимому параметру с клавиатуры, по вашему примеру я бы использовал поле name в кач-ве этого параметра. 3 - вывод всех данных на экран.